# Any guidance on how we call python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can see many examples calling python3 via `python3`.

Any many examples of calling python2 via `python`.

But, I've also seen cases of calling python3 via `python` (e.g. here https://spacy.io/usage#quickstart ).

So, I'm confused. Is this incorrect or is it normal to interchange how you call Python3? Anyone know of any guidance from the Python team?

Comment: Not sure if it helps but in anaconda prompt, for Anaconda3, Python 3 is called via `python`. In debians like Ubuntu, depending on which version of Python is installed, you can call the specific version of Python with the version prefix: `python3` .

Comment: in debians like ubuntu , if you have both versions are installed then try creating alias to call python3 as python in .bashrc file in home . or execute `echo "alias python='python3'" >> ~/.bashrc `

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better off forgetting about python 2 since 2.7 support ends in Jan 2020.

People tend to use python3 when both versions are installed but realistically you should be using some form of virtualenv where you'd just reference it via python anyway

Answer (score 0):

In most cases I have seen python3 for python3 and python for python2.

If you are using a virtual environment you do it by using python.

I guess there is no right and wrong way as far as I know.

You only need to make sure where are you pointing and what and you are good to go.